# Как на Си в целой переменной (регистр) изменить какой либо бит?

Tags: c, переменные, c++

Нужно на Си изменить в целой переменной изменить бит, так чтобы не затронуть остальные?

Comment: Найдите книжечку по СИ и почитайте там о логических операциях.
С помощью них можно работать с битами.

Comment: Вот пара макросов


      #define setbit(var,n) ((var) |= (1LL << (n)))
      #define clrbit(var,n) ((var) &= ~(1LL << (n)))


за величиной nbit следите сами.

Приведение к 1 к типу long long реально нужно для 64-разрядных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов. Но по моему так будет лучше всего:

```
// Присваиваем BIT2 - (0?1 << 2), вместо 2 номер любого бита с которым хотите работать!
        #define BIT2       (0?1 << 2)

        static int per; //Ваша переменная

        void set_bit2(void) //Функция которая будет устанавливать Ваш бит 
        {
           per |= BIT2; //Установка соответствующего бита
        }

        void clear_bit2(void) //Функция которая будет затирать Ваш бит 
        {
           per &= ~BIT2; //Стираем соответствующий бит
        }
```

Как то так, но если хотите можете вспомнить битовые поля ))